# Make mutliple pin annotations buttons to segue to an other view controller (swift 3)

Tags: swift, button, annotations, mapkit, segue

I have two pin annotations on my map. I created a info button to perform the segue. But the button appears only on one annotation. Can anyone help me please? For the annotations I created a function that I put into the viewdidload method.

Here`s the code:

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapVC: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locManager: CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        meinkartenPunkt1()
        meinkartenPunkt2()

        locManager = CLLocationManager()
        locManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        mapView.delegate = self    
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView,didUpdate userLocation: MKUserLocation){
        mapView.region.center=userLocation.coordinate
        mapView.showAnnotations(mapView.annotations, animated: true)
    }

    func meinkartenPunkt1() {
        let breite: CLLocationDegrees = 8.737653
        let länge: CLLocationDegrees = 47.504333

        let Koordinaten = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(länge, breite)

        let Span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let Region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(Koordinaten, Span)

        mapView.setRegion(Region, animated: true)

        let Stecknadel = MKPointAnnotation()
        Stecknadel.coordinate = Koordinaten

        Stecknadel.title = "Heiligberg"


        mapView.addAnnotation(Stecknadel)
    }

    func meinkartenPunkt2() {
        let breite: CLLocationDegrees = 8.734345
        let länge: CLLocationDegrees = 47.508456

        let Koordinaten = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(länge, breite)

        let Span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.01, 0.01)

        let Region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(Koordinaten, Span)

        mapView.setRegion(Region, animated: true)

        let Stecknadel = MKPointAnnotation()
        Stecknadel.coordinate = Koordinaten

        Stecknadel.title = "Kanti Rychenberg"

        mapView.addAnnotation(Stecknadel)
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{
        if annotation is MKUserLocation {return nil}

        let reuseId = "pin"

        var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId) as? MKPinAnnotationView
        if pinView == nil {
            pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            pinView!.canShowCallout = true
            pinView!.animatesDrop = true
            let calloutButton = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)
            pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = calloutButton
            pinView!.sizeToFit()
        }
        else {
            pinView!.annotation = annotation
        }

        return pinView 
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, 

    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
            if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
                performSegue(withIdentifier: "bookDetails", sender: self)
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking at your source code, I cannot directly see an answer, however I see an immediate problem. You do some important setup on the pinView, while it is nil. To be honest, this code certainly crashes, if it is ever reached:

```
if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView!.canShowCallout = true
```

Luckily for you, pinView never is nil however, as the mapView creates the pinView successfully. What you probably want to do, is to set the calloutButton, if it is not set. So instead of `if pinView == nil` you write:

```
if pinView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView == nil {
  // Initialize the rightCalloutAccessoryView here
}
```

**Tip:** In general you should avoid force unwraps with `!` as it leads to crashes. Try to use [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) with `?` instead.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Helped a bit. But I still can`t figure out why the function for the button works only for one annotation...